# Echo the number of posts being displayed

Tags: posts, wp-query, query-posts, count

I had this code working as I needed it to...but now I need to add a post count where the "**____**" is, beside "posters", so I can manipulate the css depending on how many posters are showing, for example: `<div id="posters1">` or `<div id="posters2">` or `<div id="posters3">`, etc.

I believe this can be done with [`$post_count`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) or [`$found_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) but I'm not sure where to place it and or where to move the posters `div` (ie: inside the loop?):

```
<div id="posters_ _ _ _">
    <?php 
        $movieNumber = 1;
        $today = date('Ymd');
        $posts = array (
            'post_type' => 'movie',
            'posts_per_page'   => -1,
        );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $posts );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

            $attachment_id=get_field('movie_poster',$post->post_id);
            $size = "poster"; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size) 
            $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $size ); // url = $image[0], width = $image[1], height = $image[2];

            echo '<div class="poster"><a class="various" rel="movies" href="#fancy' . $movieNumber++ . '"><img src="' . $image[0] . '" /></a></div><!-- #poster -->';

        endwhile; 
    ?>
</div><!-- #posters -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rearrange your code and use `post_count`;
example:

```
    <?php 
        $movieNumber = 1;
        $today = date('Ymd');
        $posts = array (
            'post_type' => 'movie',
            'posts_per_page'   => -1,
        );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $posts ); ?>
    <div id="posters<?php echo $loop->post_count; ?>">
    <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
...etc...
```

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I was asking. I didn't know the `$loop->post_count` part or where to put the `div`.

Answer (score 0):

Before your  you have to create a new query then count the results:

```
global $wpdb;
$count = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type='movie'");
<div id="posters<?php echo $count; ?>">
```

Comment: I'm not getting any # output with that code, just `<div id="posters">`

Comment: Hey, sorry. i remembered that you have to replace 'post_id' to 'ID' i edited it in my answer.

Comment: That works now. So, I have 5 posts total right now...but if I change my `posts_per_page` to "3" instead of "-1", the $count is still the number of posts (5). I need the $count to be limited to the number of posts being displayed, no the total number of posts.

Comment: you can add 'LIMIT 3' at the end of the query but it will not be dynamic and i don't believe there is another way since you change it from the inside and want to affect the outside.

Comment: right, that was my original question: how to make it so it's all together (no inside vs. outside).

Answer (score -1):

Simply declare a variable above
like `$i=0;`
and use `$i++` in while loop

`echo $i;` where you want to show number of posts displaying.

may it will work

Comment: yes, you can do it this way! Just append the html in a variable if you need counter to show before it and add html after it